# Can't use GitKraken on private repositories

Tags: git, git-gui

I've been using GitKraken for a while now, since about May of this year and it never gave me any trouble, except for now.
I was working on a school project and GitKraken now prevents me from opening its repository, because, apparently, this is now a Pro feature, although, I have a Github Pro account, which I use to login in Gitkraken, so, I should have access to Pro features, but I don't.

Any help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GitKraken [edition page](https://www.gitkraken.com/pricing#gk-git-client) on their website shows that working with private repos is a paid feature *of the KitKraken software*. Your GitHub Pro account doesn't mean you get GitKraken Pro features. It's a case of different companies with paid software editions both called "Pro", but with their own benefits.

If you want to use private repos with GitKraken, you'll have to make the leap from the free tier to the paid tier -- or look at other alternatives.

GitKraken provides complimentary upgrades to GitKraken Pro [for verified students](https://www.gitkraken.com/github-student-developer-pack). To make use of this benefit:

- Sign up for the [GitHub Student Developer Pack](https://education.github.com/pack) from GitHub. This requires verifying your student status.
- Log in to GitKraken using your GitHub account. GitKraken will validate that your GitHub account is enrolled in the Student Developer Pack, and provide access to Pro GitKraken features according to their own program.

Comment: But here says otherwise https://www.gitkraken.com/github-student-developer-pack

Comment: @Educorreia This is specifically about a “GitHub Student Developer Pack”. Is that what you have?

Comment: @Educorreia IF (and only if) you have the GitHub Student Developer Pack (a free upgrade to Pro service tier from GitHub, available only to verified students), then GitKraken will ALSO provide a free upgrade to Pro GitKraken

Comment: Yes, that's what I have

Answer (score 1):

According to GitKraken's website, [private repos are not available in the free tier of GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/pricing#gk-git-client). You need the Individual or Pro plan.

Comment: I know, but despite having GitHub Pro (student pack), I'm not getting GitKraken Pro with it